# Compare if values from a list are greater than X

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this one, It contains IPs with their name, and the remaining IPs of their range, I would like to only remove those that have more than X IPs in their range available, for example:

```
['12.123.0.111/29-name=22', '12.122.2.222/29-name=1', '12.122.2.222/29-name=5']
```

And I would like to take those values that are less than X, for example, if X is = 5, the list should be:

```
['12.122.2.222/29-name=1', '12.122.2.222/29-name=5']
```

How could it be done with those strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a list comprehension

**Ex:**

```
data = ['12.123.0.111/29-name=22', '12.122.2.222/29-name=1', '12.122.2.222/29-name=5']
X = 5

result = [i for i in data if int(i.split("=")[1]) <= X ]
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['12.122.2.222/29-name=1', '12.122.2.222/29-name=5']
```